# Information on new task created in Asana

Tags: asana

I am working on an application that needs to take some actions when certain events happen in user's Asana account (such as new task created, new project created and existing task modified). For this I plan to poll the Asana API every 15 mins and check for new activities. At the moment, for new task created event, I am polling the project for all its tasks in one go, but I do not get any time stamp in return. For timestamps I am required to make individual API calls for each task, which will be inefficient and eat into my rate quota.

Could you please let me know what is the best way for me to get information on new task or project created in Asana for a user, without impacting the rate quota a lot?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can include timestamps and other data using the `opt_fields` parameter. So for instance, if you just want to know about newly-created tasks, you can use `GET .../tasks?opt_fields=created_at,name` (assuming you want the name as well).

Hope that helps! (Also, we're working on a subscription system that lets you "listen" to events like task creation, which will be even better - but that's still in the works.)

Comment: Thanks! Let me try it out, and I will get back to you.

Comment: Works great! Will look forward to webhooks